# Function similar to vlookup: Why doesn't my indexOf work?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I would like to match the word that I need to find it the same as `<lookup>` in Excel. I intend to create a form for Example. I have a file certain big data and I will create a box for fill in data that you need then Enter it show the Description of data. Now I got stuck I don't know how to write to the script I have learned in youtube but don't have a solution that nearby with my need it nearby just `<Indexof>` function.

```
 var data = Activesheet.getRange(1,1,Activesheet.getLastRow()-1,1).getValues();
 Logger.log(data.indexOf("TPBSA"));
```

Answer (score 2):

`data` is a 2D(two dimensional) array. `indexOf` only works with a 1D array. [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)ten the array before indexOf:

```js
const data = [["A1"],["A2"],["TPBSA"],["A4"]];
console.info(data.flat().indexOf("TPBSA"));
//or
console.info(data.findIndex(e=>e[0]==='TPBSA'))
```

Comment: hi Friend  do you have the e-mail I would like to advise you Please

Comment: @Lek Advise about what? Site related questions can be discussed in site chat. If it's something else, you can fill up the contact form. See my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8404453/themaster) for more details.